# Как задать уникальный сложный индекс у строки в БД SQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

При добавлении новой строки в таблицу в БД ей автоматически присваивается индекс? состоящий из 1 цифры и т. д. по нарастающей. Возможно ли присваивать рандомные не повторяющиеся индексы например из 6 цифр или вообще из цифр и букв, и как это сделать? 
Это требуется для последующего вывода данных строки на странице по средствам GET запроса, а ссылка будет формироваться как раз на основе id строки.
Спасибо.

Comment: к меня возникло ощущение, что вы путаете понятие уникального индекса и первичного ключа. Чем вам не угодили `auto_increment` поля, почему нужно 6 символов для идентификатора? GUID вам в помощью тогда вообще. с месяц назад обсуждался такой вопрос, найти что то не могу.

Comment: uuid - неплохой вариант. Так же всега можно брать hash от уникального значения. md5 `$id = md5(microtime(true) . $someField);` sh1  `$id = sh1(microtime(true) . $someField);` или любой другой hash.

Comment: Кроме того, вы можете спокойно использовать идущие подряд индексы, а если не хотите делать их предсказуемыми клиенту - шифровать при передаче и расшифровывать при получении